# How to improve YSlow site performance grade for "Avoid CSS expressions"

Tags: performance, yslow

I am checking the grade on Yslow.  It returns me

```
**"Grade B on Avoid CSS expressions"**

There are a total of 2 expressions

   http://192.168.41.66/espritKM/esprit/public/CSS/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css
```

How can i improve it?

Comment: Is it a private IP? I can not access. Could you paste it in http://pastie.org?

Comment: show us the offending css first

Comment: Yeah, its a private IP. Well, You can find out the css here .  http://pastie.org/3414898

Comment: @Shiplu: 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255 is a private network address range

Comment: thanks @yi_H. I knew the start point of the range but not the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend:

[Avoid CSS Expressions](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_expressions)

> One way to reduce the number of times your CSS expression is evaluated
>   is to use one-time expressions, where the first time the expression is
>   evaluated it sets the style property to an explicit value, which
>   replaces the CSS expression. If the style property must be set
>   dynamically throughout the life of the page, using event handlers
>   instead of CSS expressions is an alternative approach. If you must use
>   CSS expressions, remember that they may be evaluated thousands of
>   times and could affect the performance of your page.